# Conditionally add string to HTML with Angular expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following :

```
<div>{{animalType}}</div>
```

which evaluates to `dog`.

Can I conditionally add an `s`if `animalType`evaluates to anything other than dog?

Something like this : *which doesn't work*

```
<div>{{animalType}} {{'s' : !animalType == 'dog'}}</div>
```

So I would get`cats`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize

Comment: @MikeRobinson It is not related to `pluralize` if you look the question closely

Comment: That's what I get for answering before coffee...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ternary` operator in expression as follow:

```
<div>{{animalType}}{{animalType != 'dog' ? 's' : '' }}</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do this with more than 2 items, like 'else IF' type syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
<div>{{animalType}}<span ng-show="animalType!='dog'">s</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try this simple snippet:

```
<div>{{animalType === "dog" ? animalType : "s"}}</div>
```

By the way, if you want to switch only between two values, from my point of view, logically appealing would be something like that:

```
<div>{{isDog ? "dog" : "s"}}</div>

$scope.isDog = true/false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ng-if

```
<div>{{animalType}}<div ng-if="animalType !== 'dog'">s</div></div>
```